# How can I create an SSH protocol link from my browser which will use a jump host?

Tags: ssh, url

Not sure whether this should be going at serverfault or stackoverflow but starting here.

I can create an SSH link to open in my terminal application (Secure CRT) that looks like this and it works fine:

`<a href="ssh://192.168.1.1">Open SSH</a>`

I now want to be able to create such links that will go via a jump host but I can't work out if that can be done from one of those URLs.

The sort of thing I was wondering about doing was along the lines of:

`<a href="ssh://192.168.1.1?o=ProxyJump%3Djump.host">Open SSH through jump host</a>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, AFAIK you can't use any "esoteric" options in a SSH URI. As far as I know there have been *draft* URI specs for SSH:

- https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-salowey-secsh-uri-00.html
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04

but that never became much of an actual supported standard.

I think that only part of the conventional [the URL spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) that works with many SSH clients is to provide a username and host.

```
 ssh://[user@]host[:port]
```

I could test that PuTTY supports the port-number in the URI.
The common openssh client states in the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html):

> - *ssh(1)/scp(1)/sftp(1): Add URI support to ssh, sftp and scp, e.g.
>   `ssh://user@host` or `sftp://user@host/path`.  **Additional connection
>   parameters** described in draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04 **are not
>   implemented** since the ssh fingerprint format in the draft uses the
>   deprecated MD5 hash with no way to specify the any other algorithm.*